Dragon Age Origins: The Darkspawn Chronicles DLC is the only one that doesn’t show up
I recently downloaded Dragon Age: Origins Ultimate Edition through Xbox Game Pass/EA Play on my PC. It's supposed to come with all the DLC but I only see that Warden's Keep, Stone Prisoner, Awakening, Return to Ostagar, and the Feastday gifts and pranks are downloaded. I'm trying to access The Darkspawn Chronicles and can't find a way to, not in Other Campaigns or New Game.

I don't know the reason behind it, but it might have something to do with the game launcher getting changed:

Eventually I found out that the EA app that replaced Origin was the root of the problem. Even though it was never linked to my EA account and owned solely through Steam, it still locked off my DLC. To fix it I had to boot up the EA app and repair my game files.
[source - edited for clarity]

In any case, you can download the different DLC directly through an official Electronic Arts FAQ here, and here is the direct link to Darkspawn Chronicles (hoping I'm allowed to hotlink).
I hope this works for you.
